# PHP Search and echo Array containing string

Tags: php, arrays, search, explode

This appears to be a simple task, but none of the previous posts quite addresses the nuances of this particular problem.  I appreciate your patience with a new programmer.

I want to divide a text file (comments.txt) into arrays with the tilde as a divider.  Then I want to pass a user string variable (nam) to the PHP and search for this string.  The result should echo every whole array that contains the string anywhere inside of it.

For example:
        Array
    (
        [0] => hotdog
        [1] => milk
        [2] => dog catcher
    )

A search for "dog" would produce on screen: 
hotdog dog catcher

```
<?php

 $search = $_POST['nam'];
 $file = file_get_contents('comments.txt');
 $split = explode("~", $file);

 foreach ($split as $subarray)
 {
    if(in_array($search, $subarray))
    {
       echo $subarray;
    }
 }
?>
```

The simple task is now this embarrassing mess.  If you are patient enough, could someone demonstrate the above code correctly? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: That's not how explode works. explode will only give you a single array whose indecies are denoted via the character to split on.

Comment: in_array uses a full-string match. you need substring matching, which means you need to use `strpos` on EVERY member value of the arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the input! So, I can remove explode and add strpos?  I'm confused now.  Can anyone paste my code with suggested edits?  It's very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have 'comments.txt' and it contains something like:

```
hamburger~hotdog~milk~dog catcher~cat~dogbone
```

then this should work

```
$comments = file_get_contents("comments.txt");
$array = explode("~",$comments);

$search = "dog";
$matches = array();

foreach($array as $item){         // check each comment in array
    if(strstr($item, $search)){   // use strstr to check if $search is in $item
        $matches[] = $item;       // if it is, add it to the array $matches
    }
}
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is close.  What about the passed variable?  Could I do this? <?php

$search = $_POST['nam'];
$comments = file_get_contents('comments.txt');
$array = explode("~",$comments);

$matches = array();

foreach($array as $item){         // check each comment in array
    if(strstr($item, $search)){   // use strstr to check if $search is in $item
        $matches[] = $item;       // if it is, add it to the array $matches
    }
}
var_dump($matches);
?>

Comment: yes... I was just giving you an example to go by. Try it and see if it works

Comment: Thanks again. Your solution works, but I think the problem with the above is my variable $search. It works with your variable, but not with my passed variable.  Am I doing that wrong?

Comment: You should update your question with actual data that you're using. Or  be more specific about about what is not working

Comment: You've sufficiently answered the above question.  My mistake now is an issue with $POST.  Thanks so much for your time an patience.

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to try using `file()` instead of `file_get_contents()`. This should do what you're looking for:

```
<?php
$search = $_POST['nam'];
$file = file('contents.txt');
$matches = array();
foreach ($file as $k => $v) {
    if ($a = explode('~', $v)) {
        foreach ($a as $possible_match) {
        if (preg_match('"/'. $search .'"/i', $possible_match)) {
            $matches[] = $possible_match;
        }
    }
}
print_r($matches);
?>
```

This method will allow you to maintain several different records (one in each line of the file) and interpret/process them independently.